# How to increase height of minibuffer/mini-window in Spacemacs?

Tags: spacemacs

Steps to take to appreciate my befuddlement:

- Run [Spacemacs](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs).
- Press the space bar.
- This moves the mode line up, and in the area below the mode line (which I think is all called either the mini-window or the minibuffer), displays keys that the user might wish to press next in order to execute a command, e.g. `SPC → avy word`, `TAB → last buffer`, etc. Unfortunately, only 9 lines of these are shown (when Spacemacs is maximised; 10 lines if I go fullscreen), so some of the options are hidden on a second page. Below this, there is a line that reads, `SPC- Spacemacs root (1 of 2) [C-h paging/help]`.
- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd>.
- That last line now reads, `SPC- n → next page, p → previous page, u → undo-key, h → help, a → abort`.
- Press <kbd>n</kbd>.
- Aha! Now we can see the second page's worth of options.

I'd like to make it unnecessary to have to press `SPC C-h n` to see those remaining options. I figure this can be done by increasing the height of the area under the mode line, so that all the options can fit on one page.

My questions:

1. How can I do this? I've already tried increasing `max-mini-window-height` from `0.25` to `0.5` and reloading Spacemacs, but this didn't appear to make any difference at all.
2. What is the correct terminology for the area that appears below the mode line when pressing the space bar in Spacemacs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feature is provided by [which-key](https://github.com/justbur/emacs-which-key).

The popup is actually a side window, not the minibuffer itself, so it is not affected by `max-mini-window-height`.

If your popup is at the top or bottom, increase `which-key-side-window-max-height` as necessary to eliminate the pagination. If your popup is at the left or the right, adjust `which-key-side-window-max-width` instead.

Comment: How can I do it also for the minibuffers open for `helm`?